# Django static images aren't loading with variable

Tags: python, html, django

My static images are loading as `<img src="/static/.png">` in the loaded HTML. I've looked at a bunch of Stackoverflow answers and I this is the best solution I found but it's still not working:

```
{% if post.score %}
   {% load static %}
   {% with 'images/score/'|add:post.score|add:'.png' as image %}
      <img src="{% static image %}">
   {% endwith %}
{% else %}
   <img src="{% static 'images/blog/blog-img-1.jpg" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

The web page loads but the images are blank. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like syntax error.


<img src="{% static 'images/blog/blog-img-1.jpg'%}" alt="">

Comment: I commented out that line and unfortunately the png files still don't load. The issue is that the post.score variable and the /score/ folder path isn't being appended to the image name. It just comes out as a blank .png filename

Comment: If you haven't found the solution already. Please check out possible solutions :
1. In settings. py check for  STATIC_URL = '/static/' ( which I assume you already have). However if you're trying to load it from some other directory then configure your static directory as  STATICFILES_DIRS = ["path to images /score",]. Finally if you want to use '/static/' and not bother with other directory then check if the files is in ...your_app/static/your_app/images/score/.....

Comment: thanks for the help. Unfortunately I tried that already. I have other images loading from /static/images, but trying to use variables isn't working for me. I even moved the images from /score/ to the static/images folder and still nothing